How to configure Tomcat to use SSH
I have a need to connect Tomcat to MySQL DB Server that is running remotely over SSH. I was able to configure MySQL Workbench to connect to this DB, but am unable to do the same with Tomcat.
I'd like to know if there is a guide or documentation somewhere that explains how to do this?
If not I'd like to ask how do I make Tomcat aware of the SSH key? MySQL Workbench allowed me to upload the file, but how to make Tomcat aware of the key? I'm assuming that Tomcat not being aware of the key is a part of the problem. :)
I'm not providing any code/config samples since I'm not really sure what I'm doing. :)
TIA for any guidance
